# Is it possible to render a datalist using Angular Formly?

Tags: angular-formly

I am trying to use Angular Formly to render a datalist without success. With what I have, it renders the text input element but drops the datalist markup.

The JS Bin demonstrating the problem is at http://jsbin.com/vamalasiru/edit?html,js,output.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to wrap the template in a div being that the template manipulator will only use the first element in a template if there is not root element.

The JS Bin has been updated to show the working solution.